# XSLT String Comparison

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I compare strings to create a table with XSLT?

I have an xml like this:

```
<Os>
        <O type="xyz">
            <Count>126</Count>
            <Food>Yes</Food>
            <Owner name="Jack">
                <Phone>564815</Phone>
            </Owner>
            <Date>12/12/2014</Date>
        </O>
        <O type="zyx">
            <Count>56</Count>
            <Food>No</Food>
            <Owner name="Phill">
                <Phone>826633</Phone>
            </Owner>
            <Date>09/11/2015</Date>
        </O>
</Os
```

And I want to traverse in it with for each and add a row if food='yes'.

```
  <xsl:for-each select="Os/O">
  <xsl:sort select="Count" data-type="number" />
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Count"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Food"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Owner/@name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Owner/Phone"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

I think I can do it if I say food:1 when there is food and food:0 when there is not. And then I can write an if statement food>0 but I don't want to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use <xsl:apply-templates select="Food"/> and have 2 templates, one matching where <Food> is 'Yes' and one where <Food> is 'No', but this is equivalent to <xsl:if>. Why don't you want to use <xsl:if>?
What row do you want to add?

Comment: I want to use <xsl:if> but i can't do it.
<xsl:if test=" Food='Yes' ">

</xsl:if>
I can't do it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add a row if food='yes'.

Why don't you simply use a *predicate*:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Os/O[Food='yes']">
  ...
```

Comment: I was looking for that syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with `<xsl:if>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="Os">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="O">
        <xsl:sort select="Count" data-type="number" />
        <xsl:if test="Food='Yes'">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Count"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Food"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Owner/@name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Owner/Phone"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: One good reason to avoid using `xsl:if` in this type of situation is the behavior of the `position()` function.

Comment: can you elaborate? The `xsl:if` here only governs output, not traversing the source tree.

Comment: If you try to number your table rows using `position()`, you will see a gap in the numbering for every `O[not (Food='yes')]`. There are other methods to number the rows, but they are either less efficient (counting preceding-siblings) or require repeating of the same logic (`xsl:number`).  -- This also suggests that the double filtering (first by `xsl:for-each`, then by `xsl:if`) is less efficient overall - but it may depend on the specific processor implementation.

Comment: Ah yes, I see; your solution wouldn't suffer from that. Thanks!